# Box2D debug draw in a specific layer

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, box2d, cocos2d-x

[This](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/09/wrapping-box2d-debug-into-a-cocos2d-layer/) article tell how to wrap Box2D debug draw in a layer. But I do not understand why it is being drawn in the specific layer. As far as I don't know OpenGL, I don't understand where it is being drawn at all. But my problem is that I want to draw in a specific layer, so that I could put that layer on top of all layers and make Box2D shapes always visible.

Today I have found the [solution how to do debug draw Box2D shapes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282391/how-to-enable-box2d-debug-draw-with-coco2d-x-3-0-beta-2) but I cannot draw in a specific layer. Could you help me understand where it is being drawn **so I could draw the Box2D shapes on top of my sprites. I want to bring them front.**

Comment: Box2d debug draw is drawn in 0th layer..so take all your sprite z-order below 0…like -1, -2,…that shows debug shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add another layer above your current layer.

And you can add the code you post here in the up layer then everything should be working.

Comment: How do you understand in which layer the code draws? I don't understand in which canvas the drawing is being done.